# find minimum key in dictonary with same values in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value-coding

hi i want to sort my c# dictonary to find the lowest key with same values in c# dictonary
my dictionary values looks like

```
    [4, 29]
    [7, 29]
    [10, 32]
    [1, 32]
    [8, 32]
    [9, 38]
    [2, 38]
```

i want the result like this >

```
    4 is the lowest key for the same value 29
    1 is the lowest key for the same value 32
    2 is the lowest key for the same value 38
```

i have tried with foreach loops but it seems very difficult and complicated
is there is some easy way to do this in c#
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution for your issue:

```
d.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
    .Select(grouping => $"{grouping.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).First()} is the lowest key for the same value {grouping.Key}");
```

It uses LINQ to group the dictionary entries by value, and then find the smallest key within each grouping.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = dictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
   .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Key).First());
```

Test:

```
foreach(var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} is the lowest key for the same value {item.Value}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that doesn't sort to find the smallest value for each key. Sorting using [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) is *O(NLogN)*, whereas using [`Min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netframework-4.8) is *O(N)*.

```
var grouped = d
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .Select(grp => (grp.Key, grp.Min(grp => grp.Key)));

foreach (var (Key, Min) in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Min} is the lowest key for the same value {Key}");
}
```

Output:

```
4 is the lowest key for the same value 29
1 is the lowest key for the same value 32
2 is the lowest key for the same value 38
```